# How to fetch corresponding record for comma separated values in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a string with commas in a `Label` now i want to fetch all values separated with commas in a new row of `Gridview` on the same page in asp.net.

Example:

**input:**

```
delhi,haryana,punjab,u.p
```

**output:**

```
Delhi

Haryana

Punjab

u.p
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to separate the label text using string functions and then use something like -

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = first value;
        dr[1] = second value;
        dr[2] = third value;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

try it.

don't forget to write these two most important lines of code-

```
 Gridview.DataSource = dt;
 Gridview.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks mr.Anand but i think u haven't understand my question it is like that i have a label on top of my gridview which have city values with (,)s like delhi,gzb,noida,a,y,z,x...... Now i want to see cities in city coloum of my grid view with new line. Note one row have 1 city only i.e no of cities=no of rows in gridview and each row have a single city name. Please help me hope u understand otherwise i will send u code.

Comment: i think you should watch out this code one more time, this can code can help you and tell me in which step exactly you are facing problem.